# Repeat (vertical) is not working in divs

Tags: image, html, background, vertical-alignment

I am currently testing a few things with DIVs instead of always using tables.

So I created a small design like:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header"><h1>Header of the page</h1></div>
    <div style="width: 27px; float: left;"><img src="style/images/top_left_corner.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <div style="width: 859px; float: left;"><img src="style/images/top_bar.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <div style="width: 28px; float: left;"><img src="style/images/top_right_corner.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <div style="width: 27px; float: left;"><img src="style/images/left_vert_bar1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <div style="width: 859px; float: left;">
        <div id="top_content">
            <div id="explanation">
                <span>Some text comes here</span>
            </div>

            <div id="form">
                <form method="post" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <label for="file">File:</label>
                    <input type="file" name="datei" size="40" maxlength="100000" />&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Submit" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 28px; float: left;"><img src="style/images/right_vert_bar1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <div class="left_dyn">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="middle_content">
            <div id="form_output">Here is the outcome of the Form</div>
        </div>
    <div class="right_dyn">&nbsp;</div>
    <div style="width: 27px; float: left; clear: left;"><img src="style/images/left_vert_bar2.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <div id="placeholder">&nbsp;</div>
    <div style="width: 28px; float: left;"><img src="style/images/right_vert_bar2.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <div style="width: 27px; float: left;"><img src="style/images/bottom_left_corner.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <div style="width: 859px; float: left;"><img src="style/images/bottom_bar.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <div style="width: 28px; float: left;"><img src="style/images/bottom_right_corner.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <div id="footer"><span>Some Footer Text</span></div>
</div>
```

Now the DIVs with `class="left_dyn"` and `class="right_dyn"` show a background image which has been setup in my CSS file and should repeat vertically, when there is some content in the DIV `id="form_output"`

This is how `class="left_dyn"` and `class="right_dyn"` look like in the CSS file:

```
/* Dyn Design */
.left_dyn {
         background: url('../images/left_dyn_bar.jpg') repeat-y scroll;
         width: 27px;
         float: left;
}

.right_dyn {
         background: url('../images/right_dyn_bar.jpg') repeat-y scroll; 
         width: 28px;
         float: left;
}
```

However when I enter some content in the DIV `id="form_output"`, the DIV `class="left_dyn"` and `class="right_dyn"` grow in height, but the bakcground image does not repeat vertically :(

I have got the impression that I do not see the wood with all those trees.

Comment: Are you sure it's because there's nothing within those divs? The divs will only grown to the size of the elements within so if there's nothing there it'll have no need to tile.

Comment: I see what you mean! But how could I go about changing this? I tried several ways but it always breaks the design over and over again.

Comment: Have you got an example / url we can look at?

Comment: This is the website in question http://loneswolf.de/develop/dxdiag/new/  The text is in German, hopefully that does not bother you?

Comment: Aha I see the problem now. It's because left_dyn/right_dyn do not expand with the content. An alternative would be to get rid of left_dyn/right_dyn and set the background image on the form_output div - that way the background image would always tile with the height of the content. It'd be worth looking into 'faux columns' : http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I've found a solution:

Like I mentioned above, the problem is that your left_dyn and right_dyn columns don't expand with the form_output div. One solution to the problem is to set the following css rules on these two divs:

```
padding-bottom: 32000px; /* Arbitrary number big enough to cover expanding content */
margin-bottom: -32000px;
```

This will basically expand the left_dyn/right_dyn divs to match the height of your form_output div.

You'll then have to set on your parent container as this'll hide any overflow:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

I tried editing this inline on your page and noticed it works except for a problem with your footer. This can easily be resolved by taking your footer **outside** the parent wrapper.

I've knocked up a quick demo explaining the effect here: http://jsfiddle.net/mWLL9/

Comment: no problem, glad it helped :-) - I edited my response above to include a demo to give you an example of what I meant

Comment: Yes thank you, that was very helpful and I saved that straight away to have this for the future in case I come across something similar again :)

Answer (score 0):

@C.Felix Its a very good idea, because now a days no one using `table` to create a website. Because the search engine do not crawl the tabled website or crawl slow. So always try to create table less design, its good for SEO purpose.

You can learn online from this website: [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com)